# how to get max count of records in a belongs to many relation with a where clause

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 models representing **Programs** and **Program Segments** that **Attendees** can register for.

1. **ScheduledPrograms** *which has many*
2. **ScheduledProgramSegments** *which belongs to many*
3. **Attendees** *(which belongs to many ScheduledProgramSegments)*

Attendees has a field **registered** that is a bool 1/0 to indicate if an attendee is registered or not.

I want to do a query that finds the maximum attendee registration count in a ProgramSegments for a Program. I.E. Something like

```
Max(    ScheduledProgram::find(id)->ScheduledProgramSegments->with([('attendees') => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('registered');
    }])->count();
);
```

Is there a way to write this query in Eloquent or Query Builder? Even using the Raw Expressions from Query Builder if that is the only way?

**Edit:** To clarify, I have a pivot table with a field `registered` and I would like to eager load the count of records, marked `registered`.

So far it seems that this is not possible unless I add and maintain a count field which I don't want to do, so I run am running a separate query to get the count for each individual record I retrieve from the pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

try to update this part in your query

```
$query->where('registered')->max('column_name');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after looking at my question again I realized it was hard to understand what I was saying. I have clarified it and presented my current workaround, in case you are interested.